# Maximum Repeating characters and count

Tags: java, string, character

I wanted to get the maximum repeating characters count and its relevant index. I am able to print the max repeating characters in a given string and its index. However I am unable to print the total count of repeating character. Below is my code

```
public class MaxRepeating {

static char charactercountIndex(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    int count = 0;

    char res = str.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int cur_count = 0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j))
                break;
            cur_count++;
        }

        if (cur_count > count) {
            count = cur_count;
            res = str.charAt(i);

        }
    }
    return res;

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    String str = "aaaaaaccde";
    char s1 = charactercountIndex(str);
    str.indexOf(s1);
    System.out.println(str.indexOf(s1));
    System.out.println(charactercountIndex(str));

    }
  }
```

output should <0,6>
0 is the index of character a
6 is the total time character "a" present in the string

Comment: i doubt you are getting the index right. You can google for the problem. there are multiple solutions on the internet

Comment: I am getting the index correctly, However I am not able to get the actual count of the character (here in this case "a", which should be 6)

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to a slightly different approach, there is a fairly straightforward way to do this using regex and streams.  We can try splitting the input string into like-lettered substring components using the following regex:

```
(?<=(.))(?!\\1)
```

Then, we can use `Collections.max` to find the largest string in the collection, and finally use `String#indexOf` to find the index of that substring.

```
String str = "aaaabbddddddddddddddddddddaaccde";
List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(str.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)"));
String max = Collections.max(parts, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.length()));
System.out.println("largest substring: " + max);
int index = str.indexOf(max);
System.out.println("index of largest substring: " + index);

largest substring: dddddddddddddddddddd
index of largest substring: 6
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but maybe "too much" for a beginner level.

Comment: @Amessihel I never know what is the best answer.  For a career engineer with a similar problem, this answer is probably more along the lines of what they would want to see.  For a beginner, the best answer is to correct the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this:

```
static Entry<String, Integer> charactercountIndex(String str) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> stringIntegerHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String letter : str.split("")) {
        if (stringIntegerHashMap.containsKey(letter)) {
            stringIntegerHashMap.put(letter, (stringIntegerHashMap.get(letter) + 1));
        } else {
            stringIntegerHashMap.put(letter, 1);
        }
    }

    Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = null;

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : stringIntegerHashMap.entrySet()) {

        if (maxEntry == null
                || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0) {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }
    }

    return maxEntry;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    String str = "aaaabbddddddddddddddddddddaaccde";
    Entry<String, Integer> s1 = charactercountIndex(str);
    System.out.println(s1.getKey());
    System.out.println(s1.getValue());
}
```

If you have any trouble, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the result through a local class instance (which contains both the character and its occurrences). I added a local class `CountResult`.

By the way, I fixed your code (see `// including ...` comment).

You can try and check the working code below [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler).

```
public class MaxRepeating {

    private static CountResult charactercountIndex(String str) {
        int len = str.length();
        char res = str.charAt(0);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            int cur_count = 1; // including the tested char (first occurence)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
                if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j))
                    break;
                cur_count++;
            }

            if (cur_count > count) {
                res = str.charAt(i);
                count = cur_count;
            }
        }
        return new CountResult(res, count);

    }

    private static class CountResult {
        private char maxChar;
        private int count;

        public CountResult(char maxChar, int count) {
            this.maxChar = maxChar;
            this.count = count;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("<" + maxChar + "," + count + ">");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String str = "aaaaaaccde";
        System.out.println(charactercountIndex(str));

        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, However I slightly modified to get the index value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class that you will not be bounded to count of returned parameters from method.

```
public class MyCharacter {
    private static int count;
    private static char character;
    private static int indexOf;

    public void characterCountIndex(String str) {
        int len = str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            int cur_count = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
                if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j))
                    break;
                cur_count++;
            }

            if (cur_count > count) {
                count = cur_count;
                character = str.charAt(i);
                indexOf = str.indexOf(character);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("<%d, %d>", indexOf, count);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "aaaaaaccde";
        MyCharacter myCharacter = new MyCharacter();
        myCharacter.characterCountIndex(str);
        System.out.println(myCharacter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just edit your previous answer?  It wasn't downvoted or anything :-|

Comment: is it still possible to get rid of one of my answer?

Comment: Just remove the content from the deleted answer and replace with `-------` etc.

Comment: I am little confused with my above program why is the cur_count variable is increasing every time, inside the second for loop and it gets incremented by +1 every time for every statement inside the second for loop. I am not understanding how it is getting incremented.